# Change Date format of $_REQUEST into another : Mer. 23 Janvier 2019 to 2019-01-23

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bootstrap datepicker into one of my form where I'm displaying the date into this format :

```
D. d MM yyyy (displayed : Mer. 23 Janvier 2019)
```

Since I can't save the date into my table in this format, I get the sent value with $_REQUEST before I'm saving it into my table column and want to change its format.

I tried :

```
$deliverydate = $_REQUEST['delivery_date'];
$deliverydate_conv = $deliverydate->format('Y-m-d');

or

$deliverydate_conv = $deliverydate->format('Y-mm-dd');
```

but when I

```
dd($deliverydate);
```

the value then I get an error :

```
Call to a member function format() on string
```

I tried also :

```
        $deliverydate = $_REQUEST['delivery_date'];
        $deliverydate_conv = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($deliverydate));
```

A date is returned but :

```
01-01-1970
```

My code is :
    public function hook_before_add(&$postdata) {

```
# START POPULATE the deliverydate FIELD

# QUERY
# SQL : GET the deliverydate FIELD

$deliverydate = $_REQUEST['delivery_date'];
$deliverydate_conv = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($deliverydate));
dd($deliverydate);

# UPDATE THE deliverydate FIELD WITH THE RETURNED VALUE

DB::table('orders')
->where('orderID', '=', $id)
->update(array('deliverydate' => $deliverydate_conv));

# END POPULATE the deliverydate FIELD

}
```

I would like to convert my code into :

```
2019-01-23
```

in order to be able to save it into my date table column.

Comment: the client-side should already post isodate; the PHP approach is highly questionable. typical X/Y problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: it is "unclear what you are asking" - because the whole JS code had been omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise, it's really helping. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're trying to parse a localized date string, you're going to need to use a class from the Intl PHP extension, make sure it's installed.

You can use the `IntlDateFormatter` class to define a formatter that can understand French dates. Then you tell it the date format you're using and lastly parse the date. It will produce a Unix timestamp that you can use with `date()`.

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("fr_FR", IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$formatter->setPattern('eee dd MMMM y');

$time = $formatter->parse("Mer. 23 Janvier 2019");

$date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
```

You can change the pattern to another that suits your needs using these flags: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

`date()` uses these as its format http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

And you can test the code above in this site: http://www.writephponline.com

Applied to your case, you'd need to parse `$deliverydate` and use its return as the second argument to `date()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guilherme for your clear explanation which speaks to me, unfortunately Laravel didn't recognize this class :

    Class 'App\Http\Controllers\IntlDateFormatter' not found

So I first need to find a way to make it work in Laravel, I'll keep your posted.

Comment: Two things: first is that the class is under the global namespace, you should either add a `use` statement or call it as `\IntlDateFormatter`. Second is that even if you set up namespaces correctly, your server must have this extension installed. As we don't know your stack, here's the link to the installation section of the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: You nailed it, it is working now ! Thanks a lot for your time and expertise. Cheers, Marc